# Virtualbox 15.1.14

Tags: virtualbox

I have downloaded `dpkg` file of `virtualbox 15.1.4` on my hard drive. The problem is I can not start the program. I used `dpkg -i /directory` command to install the file but something is going wrong and the program is crashing. I got this error in terminal:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.4.0-64-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
VirtualBox: Error -10 in SUPR3HardenedMain!
VirtualBox: Effective UID is not root (euid=1000 egid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000)

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

How to install missing files?

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in BIOS?

Comment: Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS. Should be enabled?

Comment: No it shoudlnt, but why dont you install it from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)?

Comment: I did. I have downloaded the file for official site of vb. Then i used 'dpkg' command to install it.

Comment: Then why dont you simply right click on it and open with *Software installer*? Or if you dont like it, you can get GDebi `sudo apt install gdebi`

Comment: Because my software-center is crashing.  I got GSplugin warning every time.

Comment: The error text tells you to run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`. So, what happens when you do? I could only guess that you are missing the linux-headers package or may be dkms...

Comment: Command not found. I don't have idea what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fastest way to add the official Oracle repository for Virtual Box to the Ubuntu software sources, download the signing key, and install Virtual Box:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib"
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-5.1
```

In case there was a release newer than 5.1. we may have to remove this version prior to installing a later version.

By doing so we make sure that all dependencies are met, and the software will be updated with most recent bugfixes (at the time of writing we're already at version 5.1.16).